# Google Tag Manager Multiple Enhanced eCommerce Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to GTM and I'm having trouble trying to submit 2 enhanced ecommerce events in the dataLayer. Only the last event seems to be getting sent when I check on Google Analytics.

I've come across http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ecommerce-tips-google-tag-manager/ which, just before the summary, seems to sum up what I've said regarding it only submitting the last one.

```
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'GBP',
            'add': {
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            }
        }
    });
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 1},
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            }
        }
    });
```

Only the checkout will be registered with Analytics. I've tried things like the following:

```
    dataLayer = [{
        'event': 'checkout',
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'add': {
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            },
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 1},
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            }
        }
    }];
```

and

```
    dataLayer = [{
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'add': {
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            },
        }
    }, {
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 1},
                'products': dataLayerProducts
            }
        }
    }];
```

But I've had no luck doing it like that either. If it just isn't possible, any helpful workarounds would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE WITH NEW CODE:**
Still only sending the last event (checkout). Code appears immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<script>
dataLayer = [];
dataLayerProducts = [];
dataLayerProducts.push({
    'name': 'Product Name',
    'id': 'SKU',
    'price': '29.95',
    'brand': 'Brand',
    'category': 'Some/Category',
    'quantity': 1
});
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'addToCart',
    'ecommerce': {
        'add': {
            'products': dataLayerProducts
        },
    }
});
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
        'checkout': {
            'actionField': {'step': 1},
            'products': dataLayerProducts
        }
    }
});
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
// Code
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a tag to fire, you need to have an event, whether that event is either from a previous push or a current one, so that's why it's always a good practice to push an `event` along **with** the data points you want to send into GA. Simo's example illustrates this perfectly. But since the dataLayer also persists key:value pairs, it will always use the latest event it sees. If you have more than one `event` pushed at the same time, then the last one pushed in overwrites previous ones. That's why you can't have multiple events in a single dataLayer.push and expect all your associated tags to fire.

What you need to do it follow Simo's example and push each data set/object into the dataLayer, along with an `event` of its own. Pushing to the dataLayer (`dataLayer.push`), rather than declaring them as in your examples, allows the built-in listener to pick up on those specific data points.

**Edit**: modifying OP's code as an example:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'addToCart',
   'ecommerce': {
      'add': {
         'products': // dataLayerProducts, one object per product
      },
   }
});
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'checkout',
   'ecommerce': {
      'checkout': {
         'actionField': {'step': 1},
         'products': // dataLayerProducts, one object per product
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you amend with a code example to help me understand? Because how I read it, when you say I need to push each data set with an event of its own, I thought that's what I was doing in the first code block of my question.

Comment: In your first block of code, you are overwriting the first event by declaring the second one. Remember that normal JS rules apply, so if you assign a value to a variable, and then assign another right after, then the last one sticks.

Comment: So I've taken your example code, and I've edited my question with the full code I'm using. But still, only the checkout event seems to be getting pushed. Analytics showing no sessions with add to cart, but the sessions with check-out show up correctly.

Comment: You'll have to show how you've configured the triggers and tags. You should have two triggers for each event (`addToCart` and `checkout`). I used your exact same code on my page and I see the hits firing, so shouldn't be a syntax issue. Just curious, why do you have two events pushed at the same time?

Comment: You were right on this, the code worked fine. My problem was I didn't have the triggers set up for each event. Once I set them up, the above code worked perfect. Thanks for the help.